# JSX Ternary Expression Behaves Differently For Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, jsx

Simple question:

JSX allows you to return a map function which will be comprised of a bunch of divs or images elements or whatever **without** having to wrap the JSX expression in one element.  However if you type out a series of DIVs explicitly without the map function, it yells at you.  See example below:

```
    <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
                {
                    (this.props.label.exampleImages.length > 0)

                    ? this.props.label.exampleImages.map((image, i)=>{
                        return <img src={image.url}
                             alt={image}
                             key={`image-${i}`}
                             style={{marginTop:10}}/>
                    })

                    : 
                        // this throws error even though above is essentially doing the same thing
                        <div className="image-placeholder"></div>
                        <div className="image-placeholder"></div>
                        <div className="image-placeholder"></div>


                }
            </div>
```

Why is this? Aren't they evaluating to the exact same thing?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Pointy JSX expressions must be wrapped in a single element error

Comment: OK, well that seems pretty clear to me. That's the nature of JSX.

Comment: So the map returns a single array?  I would think it would return something along the lines of: 
<img />
<img />
<img />

Comment: Well that's just plain old `Array.prototype.map`, and that always returns an array.

Comment: I'm not a React expert by any means; would it let you build an array with array initializer syntax and a `<div/>` tag for each value?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking... seems strange to allow it in the map function but not outside it, I guess my question was more along the lines of understanding what compiles before what..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first part of your ternary expression you're only returning one value, that is your array of images. However, when your `this.props.label.exampleImages.length > 0` statement returns false, you're returning multiple values, which doesn't makes sense, as explained here [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html).

You already have an enclosing div around your array, which is `<div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>`. What's causing you error is that you're trying to do something along the lines of: `var a = arr.length > 0 ? 1 : 1 2 3`. Which just isn't valid javascript as you can't return multiple values on a ternary expression.

Comment: But doesn't the map function return three <img /> tags that are **not** wrapped in a single element?

Comment: `map` only returns one value, an array containing all of your images.

Comment: what's frustrating in this case is that I want to return three divs **and** maintain the same direct parent element that the array benefits from.  I could map over a fake array like `var arr = [1,2,3]... arr.map(()=><div></div)` but it seems like this isn't a very elegant solution...

Comment: Yes I agree, you can wrap your `divs` in an array like `[<div ..>...</div>,<div ..>...</div>, ...]` , something like that, and you'll maintain your parent element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip that you can return array in a ternary conditional. Didn't know about that and gives me the results I want, marking as correct.

Answer (score 2):

First it's important to remember that JSX gets compiled to JavaScript and that's ultimately what gets run with JavaScript syntax rules.

Inside your ternary operator each portion needs to evaluate to a single value. example

`var myVar = maxValidNumStuff < getCurrItemNum() ? 'too many' : 'good'`

The `maxValidNumStuff < getCurrItemNum()` evaluated to a boolean, and each other portion evaluates to a string.

The Map  method [per Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) shows that the return value for `.map` is an array.

If you look at how JSX compiles each `<div>blah</div>` when you do it outside of map, you'll see that you're putting multiple expressions which upsets the single expression that the ternary operator wants.

Comment: So when it reaches javascript array form, then the JSX knows how to compile it correctly?  And one could say the array itself satisfies the wrapper condition?

Comment: It evaluates each `img` to a single React Element inside the array. So in the end it's a single value of an array, with multiple React Img elements, and then yah it compiles it correctly. If you wanted to do multiple divs like you had, you could do `(<someTag><div className="image-placeholder"></div>
                        <div className="image-placeholder"></div>
                        <div className="image-placeholder"></div></someTag>)` that way it still is a single element that's being evaluated, while the divs are children of `someTag`